# Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement interface yii\web\IdentityInterfac, null given

Tags: api, rest, authentication, yii2

Im trying to create a login api and have followed the link https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authentication.md

the above url says:

> To login a user, you may use the following code:
>
> ```
> // find a user identity with the specified username.
> // note that you may want to check the password if needed
> $identity = User::findOne(['username' => $username]);
>
> // logs in the user 
> Yii::$app->user->login($identity);
> ```
>
> where should be this line added in controller action or the class that implements IdentityInterface.

On adding the above line in controller action but i get error saying 
`Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement interface yii\web\IdentityInterface, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\basic\controllers\MyController.php on line 202` and defined
where as the class that i amy implementing Identity interface is actual a model called Myuser (app\models\myuser).

Why does it say `yii\web\User::login()` must implement identity interface?

And if it is to be added in Myuser class how are the posted parameters to be passed to the login function?

Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 3):

Your `User` model must implement IdentityInterface

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface{
    ...
}
```

Comment: its is.. i have infact added the implemets to MyUser model. Pls note im not using the default yii2 User mode. Im using my own custom model myUser activeRecord.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user);  
var_dump($user);
```

Try it, you can get the answer.

I met the same problem with you,and resolved. `var_dump($user)`,you can know

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

you can implement more than one Interface,

```
User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface, OtherInterface 
{
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled the Validation rules, check that validatePassword exists.

You are calling Yii::$app->user->login with a null value but you have to check for user exists before calling login.

ValidatePassword rule checks that user exists before calling login.

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }
```